# How to use import statement, it is outside the module at the moment

Tags: html, node.js, import, socket.io, require

I have this script in my html file:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
// can now use `require` in an ESM
```

I get the following error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Later in the Code I have:

```
// Set options as a parameter, environment variable, or rc file.
        require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
        module.exports = require("./main.js")
```

And I do all this to be able to run this line later:

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
```

Comment: There's a good reason you have to jump through hoops to make this lib work in Node. It's for browsers. *I have this script in my html file* - why is it there at all? 'module' is Node builtin.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. I had to add "module" to the script tag.

```
<script type="module"     
require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
module.exports = require("./main.js")     
const io = require("socket.io-client");
></script>
```